# Is there a faster way to convert characters to ints and print it to console for python?

Tags: python, performance, serial-port, converters

I am writing a python app that will basically read what is in one serial port, sniff it, output what it said to the console, and send it out a different serial port. And visa versa, for the other direction.

However, I need said app to output them in a the ascii number instead of the character it read. However, the problem is that when using the code `print(str(ord(s)), end=',')` seems to slow down the application considerably to the point it causes a timeout for the application sending the serial command. While using the code `print(s, end=',')` does not.

So is there a more efficient way to convert a character to an int?

As requested this is the full code that this code's method is on. It is actually started on a separate thread then the main code. There is no timeout set for the serial connections.

```
def sniff(com1, com2, b):
    while True:
        s = com1.read()   
        if b and s:
            print(str(ord(s)), end=',')
        else:
            pass
        if s:
            com2.write(s)
```

Comment: Are you missing a bracket in `print(str(ord(s), end=',')` ?

Comment: The call to `str()` is redundant, since `print()` converts everything to a string before printing anyway.  That said, I don't think the question can be answered in the current form.  Without seeing a bit more code, it's hard to tell whether you identified the bottleneck of your main loop correctly (and I have some doubts you did).

Comment: What are ```com1``` and ```com2``` - what does ```com1.read()``` return?

Comment: they are serial ports using the pySerial API. They return a single character that was read from that port.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it does not timeout (not even inconsistently) when using - `print(s,end=',')` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any faster way to get the ascii code for a character, but you can save time, by not printing that many amount of times, instead you can keep joining the characters into a string, and when the string reaches a large size, print the whole joined string out. Example -

```
def sniff(com1, com2, b):
    while True:
        s = com1.read()
        res = ''  
        if b and s:
            res += str(ord(s)) + ','
            if len(res) == <some high number>:
                print(res, end='')
        else:
            pass
        if s:
            com2.write(s)
```

---

Simple Example/Demo-

```
>>> import sys
>>> import io
>>> oldstdout = sys.stdout
>>> sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
>>> 'hello'
>>> def func1():
...     s = 'abcdefghijklmnoqrstuwxyz'
...     for c in s:
...             print(c,end=',')
...
>>> def func2():
...     s = 'abcdefghijklmnoqrstuwxyz'
...     res = ''
...     for c in s:
...             res += c + ','
...     print(res,end='')
...
>>>
>>> import timeit
>>> x = timeit.timeit(func1,number=100000)
>>> y = timeit.timeit(func2,number=100000)
>>> sys.stdout = oldstdout
>>> x
2.673666068058684
>>> y
0.41394731235161686
```

Answer (score 1):

Serial port communication a byte at a time is inherently slow, even before you start logging.  You could get farther and farther behind, and yes, if you have flow-control going on, you could easily cause your source to timeout by adding even more delay.  (If you don't have flow control, you will simply lose data.)

Byte-at-a time serial is sucky even before you add Python to it.  With Python it gets even slower.

The solution is to do more characters at a time. The first thing you do to enable this behavior is to *set the timeout value to 0 when you open the port*.  That way, read() has the option of returning anywhere from zero to a large number of characters to you.  However, you *don't* want to choose a really large number that will cause the program to stall due to lack of OS buffering on the output side.

What you want to do will then look something like this:

```
# NOTE: timeout should be set to 0 on com1!!!

def sniff(com1, com2, b):
    while True:
        s = com1.read(16)  # Tune this number...
        if not s:
            # No data received
            time.sleep(0.001)
            continue

        if b:
            display = ','.join(map(ord, s))
            print(display, end=',')
        com2.write(s)
```

If that is still going too slow, there are a few other things you could do.  Doing the write before doing the print would probably reduce latency, and if you want to go really fast, the right answer would probably be to do the write, then put the string on a queue, and then do the string stuff and printing in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read/write more than a byte at a time as [@Patrick Maupin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31845283/4279).

if `s` is actually a bytestring such as `b'abc'` then `print(*s, sep=',', end=',')` could be used on Python 3 that produces `97,98,99,` in this case. Or `print(*bytearray(s), sep=',', end=',')` on Python 2 (the code in the question uses `print` as a function that implies `from __future__ import print_function`).